# Given:Let $f:[a,b] \to R$, an integrable function on [a,b] such that $\int_a^x f(t) dt\ge 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ Prove: $f(t)\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Given:Let $f:[a,b] \to R$, an integrable function on [a,b] such that $\int_a^x f(t) dt\ge 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$
>
> Prove the following or give an opposite example/disprove: $f(t)\ge 0$

I'm having difficulties figuring out what I could use to prove this. I was thinking maybe the fundamental theorem of integral calculus since it's given in the form right away.

Comment: Does $f$ have to be continuous? If not, you can modify $f$ at finitely many points without changing the integral.

Comment: @carmichael561 no requirement for it to be continuous

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is not continuous take $f(a)=-1, f(x)=0, x\neq a$

Answer (score 2):

This is false even if $f$ is assumed continuous. Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ with $a=0$ and $b=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I hope this helps - feel free to ask for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x) = 1-x$, over the interval $[0,2]$